# Picking directory in react native

Tags: react-native, directory, uidocumentpicker

Does anyone know how to select a directory in `react-native` using `react-native-document-picker`? I have been using `react-native-document-picker` to select files of different extensions but I haven't come across yet any functionality in it to select a directory? Please guide me on the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-directory-picker](https://github.com/oceanbit-dev/react-native-directory-picker) may be help you.
A React Native module that allows you to use native UI to select a directory from the device library

Comment: Suggested lib is outdated (